# How is R passing parameters here?

Tags: r, function, arguments

I'm not that much of an OOP guy, so could someone please explain this simple concept in layman terms.

When I call foo.child from the foo.parent function, it seems to pass the A=7 argument 
down into the foo.child object and overrides or takes precedence over the A=3 default argument in foo.child as I would expect.

```
foo.parent <- function(A=7) foo.child(A)
foo.child <- function(A=3) 2+A
foo.parent(A=7)
#[1] 9
```

But when I instantiate it inside of foo.parent, the parameter A=7 does pass down or force the instantiated object to use A=7; instead it uses the child object's parameter of A=3

```
foo.child<-function(A=3) 2+A
foo.parent <- function(A=7){
  foo.child(A=3)
}
foo.parent(A=7)
#[1] 5
```

Why does that happen? And what terminology would I use to describe the differences?

Comment: `foo.parent<-function(A=7){foo.child(A=3)}` here you overwrite `A` in `foo.parent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example you do not give a value to `A` (At least not in such a way as you might thought). Try

```
foo.child<-function(A=3) 2+A
foo.parent<-function(A=7){
     foo.child(A=A)
}
foo.parent(A=7)
foo.parent()
```

instead. So, you mix here two different `A`s. The `=`sign within a `function` call defines, what happens if you do not give a value for that variable in the function call.

Comment: I was reading someone else's code where they always seem to force a default argument in the child functions (i.e. foo.child(A=3)). When I instantiate that object I would expect it to automatically override the value in the child block. Would it be correct to say that you must leave the argument empty or undefined when instantiating then (ie.. A=A).

Comment: I mean, you have simply two independent functions. `foo.child` and `foo.parent` don't share anything besides same argument variable names, but they could also be named in a different way. This might cause the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is you don't quite understand how default arguments work. So

```
foo.child = function(A=1) 2+A
```

defines the function `foo.child` that has a default argument `A=1`. So,

```
foo.child()
```

gives 3. Now in this function

```
foo.parent = function(A=3){
   foo.child(A=4)
}
```

you are **always** passing the value `A=4` to the function `foo.child`, hence,

```
foo.parent(A=7)
# 6
```

Also, when you are trying to figure out what is happening, it's helpful to have different values of `A`

Comment: so if I have a library with default arguments set... ie. I borrow foo.child(A=4) from someone's library and instantiate the object, I must change the variable inside that default from A=4 to A=A each time I instantiate it. Correct?

Comment: I think you are mixing up concepts and getting a bit confused in the process. To start with, just think of foo.child as a function. It takes in some data and returns something. If you don't pass it anything, then it will use it's default value (Proviso: I know that functions are first class objects).

Comment: between the two answers I got it now. Thanks! I would vote both if I could.